# Dynamically add Control on server-side Event

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, event-handling, dynamic

I want to add a user control when the user clicks on a button (the server-side event).
I'm able to dynamically add the control but since **it's too late on the page life cycle the events on that user control won't fire** (in this specific case, a button in that user control).

All solutions I've seen regarding this is to add the control on Page_Init (or Page_Load) something that I can't do here, also the control must stay "dynamic" so I can't just hide it and then make it visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the fact that the IDs of such controls were auto generated and asp.net matches the events of the controls by ID.

I fixed this by giving a ID to each dynamic control after they are created.

```
Control control = LoadControl("~/Controls/" + controlName + ".ascx");
control.ID = "SomeId";
parentElement.Controls.Add(control);
```